# How to open particular view controller after selecting a audio file in swift

Tags: swift

I want to open particular view controller after selecting a audio file from document directory.
I am doing this -:

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
    let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlaySoundsViewController") as! PlaySoundsViewController
    vc.recordedAudioURL = url
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
}
```

and open document directory using this -:

```
@IBAction func startBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let pickerController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.audio"], in: .import)
    pickerController.delegate = self
    pickerController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?  And what does 'opening a videw controller' mean?  I saw the same expression yesterday or the day before that.  Is that you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to present the view controller

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
    let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlaySoundsViewController") as! PlaySoundsViewController
    vc.recordedAudioURL = url
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```